# How to use a default value for undefined object property in VueJS interpolation?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

How to use a default value for undefined object property in VueJS interpolation? My `data` is a computed variable and is undefined at first before selecting a `selectedDataId` in a selectbox so vue sends a **"cannot read property 'grandChild' of undefined"** error.

P.S.: I'm using lodash

```
<div>
    {{ selectedData.child.grandChild }}
</div>

new Vue({
   data: {
       selectedDataId: null,
       selectedData: {},
       data: [ //array of objects here ]
   },
   computed: {
       selectedData() {
           return _.find(this.data, (d) => {
               return d.id == this.selectedDataId;
           });
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vue.js, but in plain JS you could check that the properties are defined with: `{{ selectedData.child && selectedData.child.grandChild }}`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use the following pattern:

```
{{ selectedData.child && selectedData.child.grandChild || 'default value' }}
```

It will safely check for `grandChild` and print "default value" if it is falsy.

Comment: Thank you! This is the most helpful answer. due to a duplicate in my declaration,  `selectedData` should not be in `data` which @GuyC pointed out. So i ended up using `{{ selectedData && selectedData.child && selectedData.child.grandChild || 'default value' }}`

Answer (score 3):

you are declaring selectedData twice, you should remove it from the data object.

as for an issue with it being undefined you could just test for this within your templates: `v-if="selectedItem"` or methods: `if (selectedItem)`

You don't really need lodash here as Vue has a built in filter method:

```
selectedData() {
    const selectedItem = this.data.filter((item) => {
        return item.id == this.selectedDataId
    })

    return selectedItem.length ? selectedItem[0] : {} // i'd set null here on fail
}
```

Rather than a default object I would probably just set the above to `null` if the `selectedItem.length` is 0. Then the above tests will work, passing an empty object will make them truthy.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
selectedData() {
    return _.chain(this.data)
        .find({id: this.selectedDataId})
        .defaults(...default object...)
        .value()
}
```